# How do I add the results to the list?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program that includes all the presidents and lets you search any letter or name to show the results of presidents associated with that letter or name. However, I am having trouble with actually adding them to the list. This is a class project, so the code is designed to meet requirements for that. Specifically, the part where it says
'Show the match
addPresidentsToList(presidents(idxReturned), idxReturned)
This is saying it isn't declared, but I'm not sure how to go about it.
Any tips or advice would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Public Class frmLab32
    Const IDX_START As Integer = 0
    Const IDX_END As Integer = 1
    Const IDX_NAME As Integer = 2

    Dim presidents() As String
    Dim headerRowNeeded As Boolean
    Private Sub frmLab32_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Populate array from file
        presidents = IO.File.ReadAllLines("USPresWithDates.txt")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Dim idxReturned As Integer = -1
        Dim idxStart As Integer = 0

        'remove names
        lstResults.Items.Clear()

        'Header row?
        headerRowNeeded = True

        'Search for matches
        Do
            idxReturned = Array.FindIndex(presidents,
                                          idxStart,
                                          Function(el) el.Split(","c)(IDX_NAME).ToLower.Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower))
            'Match Found?
            If idxReturned > -1 Then
                'Show the match
                addPresidentsToList(presidents(idxReturned), idxReturned)
                'Prepare for next search
                idxStart = idxReturned + 1
            End If
        Loop Until idxReturned = -1

        'Any names found?
        If lstResults.Items.Count = 0 Then
            'Update counter
            lblCount.Text = "0"

            'Tell User
            MessageBox.Show(text:="No match found",
                            caption:="Search Results",
                            buttons:=MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            icon:=MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you want to display and where do you want to display it? It seems that each element of your array is CSV data containing two dates and a name. Do you want to display the whole `String` or just the name part? It looks like you want to display them in a `ListBox`. Is that correct? If so, adding them to the list would, in its simplest form, involve calling `lstResults.Items.Add`.

Comment: If you have code that is attempting to call a method named `addPresidentsToList` and you're told that it is not declared, the obvious thing to do is declare it. Once you have declared a method, the obvious thing to do is implement it. It's also worth nothing that the method name implies multiple presidents while the arguments imply a single president. A method name should accurately summarise what the method does. Adding one item to a list and adding multiple items to a list are two different things. Also, method names should begin with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

My text file looks like this.

```
Washington, George
Adams, John
Jefferson, Thomas
Madison, James
Monroe, James
etc.
```

I use default names for controls in my text program but it is much better to use descriptive name like you did.

In the `Form.Load` I set the `MaxLength` property of the TextBox to 1. This will only allow a single character to be typed in the TextBox. You could set this property in the form designer and skip this line of code. Next fill the presidents array exactly as you did.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox5.MaxLength = 1
    presidents = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\Presidents.txt")
End Sub
```

Now for the search button. We need to validate the user input. A user could enter a number or punctuation character. `Char` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netcore-3.1#:~:text=Remarks-,.,bit%20numeric%20(ordinal)%20value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=Remarks-,.,bit%20numeric%20(ordinal)%20value). is a .net structure representing a character. It provides some interesting methods that can be helpful from time to time. Char.IsLetter() tells us (true or false) if a character is a letter. Just what we want to know. The only problem is a `String` is not a `Char` and `.Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `String`. Since we limited the entry to a single character we can convert this `String` to a `Char` with `CChar()`. If it is a letter we make the assignment to `SelectedLetter` otherwise we correct the user and exit the method.

Instead of all the index stuff we can use a `For Each` loop. It checks each element in presidents. `String` has a method called `StartsWith`. We can check each string in presidents to see if it `.StartsWith` the `SelectedLetter`. If it does, add it to the `ListBox`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    'Validate user input
    Dim SelectedLetter As String = ""
    If Char.IsLetter(CChar(TextBox5.Text)) Then
        SelectedLetter = TextBox5.Text.ToUpper
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a letter A - Z.", "Enter Letter")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each pres In presidents
        If pres.StartsWith(SelectedLetter) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(pres)
        End If
    Next

    If ListBox1.Items.Count = 0 Then
        'Tell User
        MessageBox.Show("No match found", "Search Results")
    End If
End Sub
```